# NuGet - install.ps1 does not get called when adding file with ZipArchive class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, zip, nuget, nuget-package

I want to add `tools\Install.ps1` into my `nuget` packages via software. This is already working with the following code:

```
Zipper.AddItem(pathToNuGetFile, pathToToolsFolder);
```

When I install the nuget package, the `Install.ps1` script is simply skipped and not invoked. But it exists! It is also unpacked in the `packages` folder.

#### Packages Folder (in Solution)

[image: packages]

#### tools (subfolder)

[image: install]

When I open the ***.nupkg** file (in NuGet-Sources-folder and **not** in the packages folder) and rename `Install.ps1` to `Install.ps`, rename it back to `Install.ps1` and save the "zip"/`*.nupkg` file, the Install.ps1 script is getting invoked!! Why?!

#### Zipper Class

```
internal class Zipper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// is adding an item to an existing Zip Archive
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pathZipFile"></param>
    /// <param name="pathItem"></param>
    public static void AddItem(string pathZipFile, string pathItem)
    {
        Program.WriteLine($"Opening archive '{pathZipFile}'..");
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(pathZipFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
            {
                Program.WriteLine("successfully opened");
                if (File.Exists(pathItem))
                {
                    Program.WriteLine($"{pathItem} is a file. Starting to add the file to the archive..");

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathItem);
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileInfo.FullName, fileInfo.Name);
                    Program.WriteLine($"{pathItem} successfully added.");
                }
                else if (Directory.Exists(pathItem))
                {
                    Program.WriteLine($"{pathItem} is a directory. Starting to recursively add the files..");

                    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathItem);
                    foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.AllFilesAndFolders().Where(o => o is FileInfo).Cast<FileInfo>())
                    {
                        Program.WriteLine($"Adding file '{file.FullName}'");
                        string relPath = file.FullName.Substring(directoryInfo.FullName.Length - directoryInfo.Name.Length);
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, relPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class FileExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> AllFilesAndFolders(this DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        foreach (var f in dir.GetFiles())
            yield return f;
        foreach (var d in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            yield return d;
            foreach (var o in AllFilesAndFolders(d))
                yield return o;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image: preview]

[image: tools]

Comment: It seems that the `Install.ps1` script was still used by other programs when you install it. You can try to confirm this by manually add `Install.ps1` script to the package, then install it to the project. Or add `tools\Install.ps1` into your nuget packages via software, then restart Visual Studio and install that package.

Comment: Manual is no solution. I want to include it automatically.Restarting VS is also not working. The nuget is manipulated/updated by a 3rd party tool (and uses the code above), so VS is not involved.

Comment: I know that Manual is no solution, I suggest manually add  `install.ps1` is to narrow the scope of this issue, if it works fine with manually add, this issue should be more related to manipulated/updated by a 3rd party tool. You can simple use NuGet Package Explorer to add it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in the `ZipArchive` class from Microsoft. When I use `7zip` to add my files, everything works like expected!

I have implemented `7zip` into the solution and changed the `AddItem` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// is adding an item to an existing Archive
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pathZipFile"></param>
/// <param name="pathItem"></param>
public static void AddItem(string pathZipFile, string pathItem)
{
    string appPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "7zip", "7za.exe");
    if (SystemInformation.Is64BitOperatingSystem())
    {
        appPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "7zip", "x64", "7za.exe");
    }

    //
    // Setup the process with the ProcessStartInfo class.
    //
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = appPath;
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    start.Arguments = $"a -r {pathZipFile} {pathItem}";

    //
    // Start the process.
    //
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        //
        // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
        //
        if(process == null)
            throw new Exception("Failed to start the 7zip Process!");

        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write(result);
        }

        process.WaitForExit();
        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
            throw new Exception($"Fehlercode von 7zip: {process.ExitCode}");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.